# Struts 2, type conversion of Dates in a List, non-default format

Tags: java, struts2

I have an action, that action has List of Dates property. The request parameters will come in "yyyy.MM.dd" format. 
In have "-coversion.properties" file (I don't want to use global type converter for this purpose).

I am not using annotations.

If it was just a single Date, not a collection, property-specific conversion would be easy. Is it possible to do apply a property-specific type conversion to the elements of a List?

Comment: you are saying that you have List<Object> and one element in it can be date and you want to detect that element first and then apply date format conversion on it. rite ?

Comment: some code would help you get an answer

Comment: Why do you need a converter for `Date` objects ? `Date` is a common type and it's already handled by Struts2... something in this question is missing.

Comment: Andrea, because I want to use a non-default (SHORT) format, for example yyyy.MM.dd

Comment: Rizstien, I want to apply date format to all elements of the List

Comment: This link provides an example of creating a converter that should work well for you. The converter converts a single date however it is clear that the values are passed an an array, so you simply need to iteratively apply the process and return a List<Date> from the converter. http://books.google.ca/books?id=HrFGgg3fPwsC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=struts2+custom+type+converter+example&source=bl&ots=XajH5HSvBO&sig=3SYIazPqFP3bv3RQb9SQ2XIeQ9c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VkUAUeLiNdGvigLP8YC4Bg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=struts2%20custom%20type%20converter%20example&f=false

Comment: After the converter exists it is trivial to have it handle the property in question via the -coversion.properties file. Out of curiosity, why not use annotations? It isn't like adding them makes thing more confusing as a matter of fact, it tends to be the other way. You look in the action and forget something different is happening, but with annotations it is harder to forget and if you copy code, you'll copy the annotation too and get the same effect where with the property file it is easy to forget. I can't see a down side and it does not require you to remove the property files that exist.

Comment: @Quaternion "By using annotations, an application should be able to avoid using any ClassName-conversion.properties files." from the docs.

Comment: That's my point... on a per action basis it would be hard to argue against them there is still a place for global conversions...

Comment: @Vladimir why dont you use for loop in action class. iterate it over List<Date> do the conversion and return back same List but formated.

Comment: I apologize, but I seriously think the question is not complete. May be you could bother to add some code and more details. Have you tried using [struts2 date tag.](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/date.html)

Comment: What control are you passing the list to? Is it drop-down, multis-elect or just some tables etc? Are you passing this back as json?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a sample code which works fine. It's structure is as above.
[image]

At first I wrote a converter in `/util/MyDateConverter.java` as below:

```
package util;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConversionException;

import ognl.DefaultTypeConverter;

public class MyDateConverter extends DefaultTypeConverter {
@Override
public Object convertValue(Map context, Object object, Class type) {
    if (type == Date.class) {
        String datePattern = "yyyy.MM.dd";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
        format.setLenient(false);
        try {
            String[] dateString = (String[]) object;
            return format.parse(dateString[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TypeConversionException("Given Date is Invalid");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Then, to use struts2 collection conversion support, I wrote `/util/MyDate.java` as below:

```
package util;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyDate implements Serializable {

    public MyDate(int myId, Date value) {
        super();
        this.myId = myId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    int myId;
    Date value;

    public Date getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Date value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getMyId() {
        return myId;
    }

    public void setMyId(int myId) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Then I told struts2 how to support collection by writing `/action/Action1-conversion.properties` as below:

```
KeyProperty_dates=myId
Element_dates=util.MyDate
CreateIfNull_dates=true
```

Then told him how to convert `MyDate.value` by writing `/util/MyDate-conversion.properties` as below:

```
value=util.MyDateConverter
```

Then I prepared `/index.jsp` as below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<s:form>
    <s:date name="dates(1).value" format="yyyy.MM.dd" id="dateSD1" />
    <s:textfield name="dates(1).value" value="%{dateSD1}" label="New Date 1" />

    <s:date name="dates(2).value" format="yyyy.MM.dd" id="dateSD2" />
    <s:textfield name="dates(2).value" value="%{dateSD2}" label="New Date 2"/>

    <s:submit value="Update" />
    <pre>
    Current Date 1: <s:date name="dates(1).value" />
    Current Date 2: <s:date name="dates(2).value" />
    </pre>
</s:form>
```

and `/action/Action1.java` as below:

```
package action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import util.MyDate;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Action1 extends ActionSupport {

    public Action1() {
        super();
        dates.add(new MyDate(1, new Date()));
        dates.add(new MyDate(2, new Date()));
    }

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    List<MyDate> dates = new ArrayList<MyDate>();

    public void setDates(List<MyDate> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public List<MyDate> getDates() {
        return dates;
    }
}
```

After running application, the `Update` button works well as expected which shows that conversions have been working well.

I hope this sample code can help you.

Reference: [Apache Struts2 Type Conversion](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-ApplyingaTypeConvertertoabeanormodel)